# A Decentralized NPM? Re: Ryan Dahl's Talk @ JSConf EU 2018

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, package-managers

I recently watched Ryan's Dahl's "Ten Things I Regret About Node.js" talk from last year (if you haven't, [give it a look](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3BM9TB-8yA)). Around 9:52, Ryan's slides remark that

> It's unfortunate that there is a centralized (privately controlled even) repository for modules.

speaking of course about NPM. He seems about to go more in depth on the subject but unfortunately is interrupted, almost fittingly, by a notification from iCloud, another behemoth of centralized storage. It likely breaks his chain of thought because he moves on to the next slide.

I've been gnawing at the idea of a decentralized package manager for the past week or so and couldn't figure how it would function. With NPM being a centralized index for essentially every available module, it's very easy to find the right choice. Have other package managers, communities, language developers or technologies used a more distributed approach? How do they function? Is it more difficult to find the right module? What even are the benefits of a package manager being decentralized, and could NPM have adopted something similar?

I'm a junior JavaScript developer who recently landed my first job. Node is the only environment I'm super familiar with and NPM is the only package manager I've used professionally. Perusing Wikipedia for the past week isn't yielding satisfying results, so I would love to hear any and all wisdom. Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use NPM (the package manager) without NPM (the service).  NPM will install packages from other locations, like Git repositories or local directories, just fine.  There are also alternatives like Yarn.

Comment: @Brad I definitely didn't know that about Git repositories, that actually opens up some cool possibilities. I do prefer Yarn at the moment, but you raise a good point about distinguishing between the service and the package manager.

Comment: Many possibilities here from *federated* services (many different npmjs.com, which nonetheless communicate amongst each other), or a true P2P architecture along the lines of a blockchain, or something in-between like BitTorrent. Each have their own pros and cons, with the distributed solutions tending towards resilience with worse performance and the centralized solutions towards speed with single-point-of-failure problems.

Comment: Think web browser, you can load a resource from anywhere, not just some monolithic repository of every web application. Does this mean it's more difficult to find good libraries to use? jQuery (and many other libraries) existed before NPM, and it's pretty popular, I'd say that's proof enough for you.